# Is there a ftp_rawlist() alternative to avoid memory problems?

Tags: php, ftp

I'm using ftp_rawlist() to obtain a list of files in a directory:

```
$files = ftp_rawlist($ftp, "-A " . $ftp_dir);// obtain hidden files without "." and ".."
```

So far so good. But some folders contains several thousand files so I'm having problems with the memory usage:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 209855912 bytes) in X on line Y

Is there any alternative to get the LIST result line by line? Maybe through ftp_raw()?

EDIT: I don't want to use ini_set('memory_limit', 'xxxM'); as I never know how much memory is needed and I don't think this would be a good practice as some hosts doesn't allow to change this value.

Comment: You can open socket connection and send raw ftp commands, and get output line by line. But you still need to store it somewhere, so you need lot of memory.

Comment: Do you have an example? I will test it. If there is no other way I will try to write the data in a local file.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1743-PHP-FTP-client-in-pure-PHP.html it implements ftp client without relying on ftp extension

Comment: @dev-null-dweller Thank you. I was testing on my own but its really an own project to realize that so this class is really perfect! I found a "new" one in wordpress: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-ftp.php I will use that and give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Try increase memory limit

```
ini_set("memory_limit", "64M")
```

64 or more MB

Also you can switch off max execution time

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: I don't want to change the `memory_limit`. I've updated my question.

Comment: @mgutt It seems to me that this is the only way out, use memoty_limit

Comment: By the way: 67108864 = 64M and 209855912 = 200M. There could be folders with much more files as well.

Comment: P.S. I don't have any problems with max_execution_time as I transfer only x files per request (next request continues at the last position).